# Laravel 5 Command not Returning Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use commands so I can queue them because of a bunch of requests that will take 30-90 seconds to complete. The only issue is that the command is not returning data to my controller like I hoped it would, instead, all I'm getting is a convenient (sarcasm) "null". Here's some code snippets from my files, and thanks for any help!

HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    var_dump($this->dispatch(new \App\Commands\GetFeedCommand("http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.atom")));
}
```

GetFeedController

```
use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class GetFeedCommand extends Command implements ShouldBeQueued {

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public $guzzle;
    public $uri;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($uri)
    {
        $this->guzzle = new Client;
        $this->uri = $uri;
    }

}
```

GetFeedControllerHelper

```
use App\Commands\GetFeedCommand;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class GetFeedCommandHandler {

    /**
     * Create the command handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the command.
     *
     * @param  GetFeedCommand  $command
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(GetFeedCommand $command)
    {
        return $command->guzzle->get($command->uri)->xml();
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

If you `queue` the command - then when you run it nothing will happen instantly, so it returns null. Meanwhile the command will run in the background on your queue processing system separately.

If you need an immediate reply - then just run the command without the queue.

Comment: Good point, I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks for the help!